# I can't figure out how to make ccls work in vim on ubuntu

Tags: c++, c, clang, coc.nvim

Here is my problem :
I've installed coc plugin on vim and it work perfectly with all language except with C/C++.

The problem is with C/++, ccls don't find my system libraries... (I tried with clangd too, I had the same problem).

Here is my coc-settings.js :

```
{
  "languageserver": {
    "ccls": {
      "command": "ccls",
      "rootPatterns": [".ccls", "compile_commands.json"],
      "filetypes": ["c", "cpp", "c++", "objc", "objcpp"]
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my compile_commands.json (compiled whit CMake, placed at my project root and my vim current directory) :

```
[
{
  "directory": "/media/romain/Donnees/Programmation/C++/cmake/fxplorer/build",
  "command": "/usr/bin/g++ -Dmydebug -I/media/romain/Donnees/Programmation/C++/cmake/fxplorer/src -I/media/romain/Donnees/Programmation/C++/frameworks -I/media/romain/Donnees/Programmation/C++/frameworks/files -I/media/romain/Donnees/Programmation/C++/libs/json -I/media/romain/Donnees/Programmation/C++/libs/imgui -I/media/romain/Donnees/Programmation/C++/libs/imgui/backends -I/media/romain/Donnees/Programmation/C++/cmake/fxplorer/../imgui_custom-menus/src -isystem /media/romain/Donnees/Programmation/C++/libs/boost-install/include -isystem /media/romain/Donnees/Programmation/C++/libs/glew-2.1.0/include -isystem /media/romain/Donnees/Programmation/C++/libs/glfw-3.3.7/include -isystem /media/romain/Donnees/Programmation/C++/libs/FreeImage/Source -isystem /media/romain/Donnees/Programmation/C++/libs/FreeImage/Wrapper/FreeImagePlus -g -O0 -g3 -std=gnu++17 -o CMakeFiles/fxplorer.dir/media/romain/Donnees/Programmation/C++/cmake/imgui_custom-menus/src/CustomMenus.cpp.o -c /media/romain/Donnees/Programmation/C++/cmake/imgui_custom-menus/src/CustomMenus.cpp",
  "file": "/media/romain/Donnees/Programmation/C++/cmake/imgui_custom-menus/src/CustomMenus.cpp"
},
... other stuff here ... (but can't put it because it's too long)
{
  "directory": "/media/romain/Donnees/Programmation/C++/cmake/fxplorer/build",
  "command": "/usr/bin/g++ -Dmydebug -I/media/romain/Donnees/Programmation/C++/cmake/fxplorer/src -I/media/romain/Donnees/Programmation/C++/frameworks -I/media/romain/Donnees/Programmation/C++/frameworks/files -I/media/romain/Donnees/Programmation/C++/libs/json -I/media/romain/Donnees/Programmation/C++/libs/imgui -I/media/romain/Donnees/Programmation/C++/libs/imgui/backends -I/media/romain/Donnees/Programmation/C++/cmake/fxplorer/../imgui_custom-menus/src -isystem /media/romain/Donnees/Programmation/C++/libs/boost-install/include -isystem /media/romain/Donnees/Programmation/C++/libs/glew-2.1.0/include -isystem /media/romain/Donnees/Programmation/C++/libs/glfw-3.3.7/include -isystem /media/romain/Donnees/Programmation/C++/libs/FreeImage/Source -isystem /media/romain/Donnees/Programmation/C++/libs/FreeImage/Wrapper/FreeImagePlus -g -O0 -g3 -std=gnu++17 -o CMakeFiles/fxplorer.dir/media/romain/Donnees/Programmation/C++/libs/imgui/misc/cpp/imgui_stdlib.cpp.o -c /media/romain/Donnees/Programmation/C++/libs/imgui/misc/cpp/imgui_stdlib.cpp",
  "file": "/media/romain/Donnees/Programmation/C++/libs/imgui/misc/cpp/imgui_stdlib.cpp"
}
]
```

And here my .ccls file (placed in the same dir that the compile_commands.json file) :

```
"clang": {
    "args" : ["-std=C++17"]
}
```

And with this config I have errors likes : 'can't find "vector" in namespace "std".
I have errors like ccls don't even read the compile_commands.json file because it can't find any function/method from libraries linked in it.

I can't figure what I'm doing wrong... ?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: @Gerhardh  thank you for this small error correction, but unfortunately, it didn't resolve the problem :/

Comment: Have you tried using this? https://github.com/m-pilia/vim-ccls (I do not suggest, that this is needed, but it may help you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been digging for some time now and I found the solution.
I moved back on clangd instead of ccls but the steps should be the same. (ccls is based on clangd)

I had 2 problems :

- 1 : clangd wouldn't find my system header librairies (even with the flag `-isystem` in my `compile_command.json` generated via CMake).

So I had to give it to it.
Like these settings will be for all my projects, I decided to make this configuration global for clangd.

For this, you need to create a file in `YOUR_CONFIG_FOLDER/clangd/config.yaml` (for me - Unbuntu 22 -  it was `~/.config/clangd/config.yaml`, you need to create the folder `clangd` if it does not exists yet.)
After that, you need to put the path of where are your system headers and your compiler headers (for me : gcc, g++).
This is the content of my file :

```
CompileFlags:
  Add: [-I/usr/include, -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu, -I/media/romain/Donnees/Programmation/C++/frameworks, -I/usr/include/c++/11, -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11, -std=c++17]
```

For more information about this file and its format, you can visit the [clangd website](https://clangd.llvm.org/config).

Ok after that, the system header missing problem was gone.
But like I said, I had another problem.

For some of my project files, the weren't in a sub-folder of my project. (because the are a frameworks that a write for all my apps).
I didn't want to move them.

The problem is that when a file is not in a subfolder of your project, clangd change the project_root folder for this file and don't found the `compile_command.json` file anymore.

But luckly, clangd give the possibility to create a config file per folder.
So that's what I did, I created a config file for my frameworks folder.

The method is to create a file named `.clangd` and to put it in the root folder of your frameworks directory.

The `.clangd` file have the same syntax of the `config.yaml`.
Here is the content of mine :

```
CompileFlags:
  Add: [ 
-I/media/romain/Donnees/Programmation/C++/libs/json,-I/media/romain/Donnees/Programmation/C++/libs/imgui,-I/media/romain/Donnees/Programmation/C++/libs/imgui/backends,-I/media/romain/Donnees/Programmation/C++/libs/glfw-3.3.7/include,-I/media/romain/Donnees/Programmation/C++/libs/FreeImage/Source,-I/media/romain/Donnees/Programmation/C++/libs/FreeImage/Wrapper/FreeImagePlus,-I/media/romain/Donnees/Programmation/C++/libs/boost-install/include,-I/media/romain/Donnees/Programmation/C++/libs/glew-2.1.0/include]
```

I just did a copy of my cmake includes when I use my frameworks.

And that was it, clangd work perfectly fine now.
I hope this one will help you too if your C++ LSP don't work as expected.